# Oracle Apex 5.1 installed translated applications -encoding error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

After loading oracle apex translation language i am facing special character

encoding. my client and server characterset are AL32UTF8.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the Installation Guide and my experiences, you must set NLS_LANG before execute translation scripts, making sure that the character set id AL32UTF8. For example:

> Bourne or Korn shell:

```
NLS_LANG=American_America.AL32UTF8
export NLS_LANG
```

> C shell:

```
setenv NLS_LANG American_America.AL32UTF8
```

> For Windows based systems:

```
set NLS_LANG=American_America.AL32UTF8
```

For more details: [Oracle Apex Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/installing-translated-versions-of-Oracle-AE.htm#HTMIG29175)

Current test Sample: [image: Apex translation]

Comment: i did that but still have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Phanny, check the NLS configuration for your cliente session using `SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'LANGUAGE') FROM DUAL;` right before execute the transation to validate if it's set as required. I have tested fr language and it work as espected.